# Can someone explain me why the following algorithm for LIS is not O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, erlang, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, lis

The following code traverses the list once and finds the LIS. I don't see why the DP algorithm should take O(n2).

```
//C
int lis(int *a, int l){
  if(l == 0) return 1;
  else if(a[l] > a[l - 1])  return  1 + lis(a, l - 1);
  else  return lis(a, l - 1);
}

int main(){
  int a[] =  { 10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60 };
  cout << lis(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) - 1);
}

% erlang
lis([_H]) -> 1;
lis([H1, H2 |T]) when H1 > H2 ->  1 + lis([H2|T]);
lis([_H|T]) -> lis(T).

main() ->  lis(lists:reverse([ 10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60 ])).
```

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood something, but why do you think your erlang implementation is not O(n)?

Comment: Isn't the complexity of my c and erlang code same?
According to wikipedia and http://goo.gl/R1WHrP, this problem takes O(n2) which can be improved to O(n logn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation of `lis/1` function is O(n), I don't see any reasons to doubt. But there is some problem. You implementation doesn't actually calculate valid LIS. Try

`lis(lists:reverse([1,2,3,4,1,2]))`

for error example. Longest increasing sequense is [1,2,3,4], right? But your algorith returns 6 as result.

- First error in your algorithm in that you increase `result` each time, when you encountered element that greater than previous. But you should increase `result` only if current element is greater that *greatest element* of your current LIS. So (according example above) you should remember `4` and not increase `result` after you detected then `2` is greater than `1`.
- But this not only thing you have to do. Consider sequence `1 2 3 6 4 5`. For 5 first elements LIS has length of 4. But there is TWO possible options there - either `1 2 3 4` or `1 2 3 6`. Which you should take as actual LIS?
- And so on, and so on...

Another example comes directly from [wiki page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)

Sequence `[0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15]` has LIS `[0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15]` (e.g., `6` elements), but your algorythm says `9`.

And, (correct me, if I'm wrong), LIS implementation must return subsequence itself, but not only its length.

Comment: Thank you Viacheslav Kovalev and @Roberto Aloi! Can you please point out why it works for my example and not for all cases?
I think, Returning the subsequence along with length using the above algorithm only takes additional space and not additional time.

Comment: @functional_overflow, I've updated (actually, corrected) example that demostrates your algorith misbehaviour.

Comment: Thanks, i understood that my algorithm is wrong. I don't understand how/where it is wrong. I was hoping you would point out the mistake in my solution.

Comment: @functional_overflow I've tried to briefly explain some of your algorithm flaws. But I'd recommend your to start from original O(n^2) algorithm and try to get which problems does it solve.

Answer (score 2):

**Good news:** the above implementation is not quadratic.

**Bad news:** the above function does not calculate the longest subsequence of increasing elements (defined as the [LIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)).

To respond to your question, the actual LIS problem has quadratic complexity, not the DP algorithm itself, which is merely a step towards the final solution. In fact, the DP algorithm is repeated for all elements of the list (you need to calculate all the DP[i]), which is why the complete algorithm is categorized as O(n^2).